# JavaScript: Get Finish, DOMContentLoaded & Load Time in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I was working on to Find-Out Google Chrome Load Times using JavaScript.

I need to get #Finish, #DOMContentLoaded & #Load-Time in Google Chrome using JavaScript like this:

[image]

I wrote the code below, that is returning me the negative value, don't know what is it.

```
<script>
var time = (window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) / 1000;
console.log(time);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var t = performance.timing; 
    console.log((t.loadEventEnd - t.responseEnd));
  }, 0);
```

But while we are measuring milliseconds I don't think you can obtain exactly the same values like shown in chrome inspect element.